# What is faster - insert into new table, or delete from existing table?

Tags: insert, sqlite, delete

I have a huge DB that I want to scale down, to only look at my area of interest. Initially I wanted to write the records I'm interested in onto a new database and table. However, this is taking for ever, so I'm wondering if it might be faster to delete the records I do not want. I already got a copy of the database, so there would be no problem to delete.

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7) 
SELECT OldTable1.C1, OldTable1.C2, OldTable1.C3, OldTable1.C4, OldTable1.C5, OldTable1.C6, OldTable1.C7 
FROM OldTable1 
INNER JOIN OldTable2.C5 ON OldTable2.C5 = OldTable1.C5 
WHERE OldTable2.C8 = 70
```

If I would delete I would delete all data from OldTable1 that did not match the inner join and where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on the details of your database.

Factors include:

- Number of records to be copied/retained;
- Whether you're keeping all columns or not; and
- Number of indexes on old and new table (as alluded to by @a_vlad).

If I needed to delete most of the records in a table, I have definitely had times where it was faster to copy the records to another table, `TRUNCATE` the first table, and then copy the records to be saved back to the first table (with all indexes, constraints, etc.; the other table would usually be stripped down to just the raw data).

That said, if you're keeping notably more records than you're deleting, and if you don't have a lot of indexes on the original table, it's entirely possible that deleting would be faster.

NOTE: If you don't need to keep all columns, then the `INSERT` method is almost certainly your best bet.